# Mdriven designer click once

Tags: modeling, mdriven

When following the tutorial Mdriven overview part one. Computer is unable to install Mdriven designer click once.

Error message: This type of file may damage the computer
Would you still like to keep Gaffr  (2)application?

If i keep the file another error message comes up.

Error message: Unable to start the application program. Contact the supplier of the application.

If i then click information about the problem this comes up

```
  INFORMATION ON PLATFORM FORM
Windows: 10.0.16299.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime: 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll: 4.7.2556.0 built by: NET471REL1
clr.dll: 4.7.2600.0 Built by: NET471REL1LAST
dfdll.dll: 4.7.2556.0 Built by: NET471REL1
dfshim.dll: 10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

Sources
Distribution URL: File: /// C: / User / erikh / Downloads / Fork% 20 (1) .application

identities
Distribution Identity: Gaff.application, Version = 7.0.0.9779, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 65dfc6bd5d830589, processorArchitecture = msil

PROGRAM SUMMARY
* Application programs used only online.
* Parameter with trust credentials has been entered.
SUMMARY OF ERROR
Below is a summary of errors. You can find more information about these further down the log file.
* Activation of C: \ Users \ erikh \ Downloads \ Gaffr (1) .application resulted in an exception error. The following error messages were detected:
+ The deployment and application program security zones do not match.

SUMMARY OF MISCELLANEOUS TRANSACTIONS IN THE COMPONENT SITUATION
No transaction errors found.

WARNINGS
No warnings were displayed when the operation was performed.

PROCESS ACTION
* [2018-01-14 19:33:14]: Activation of C: \ Users \ erikh \ Downloads \ Gaffr (1) .application has started.
* [2018-01-14 19:33:14]: Processing of the distribution manifesto has ended.
* [2018-01-14 19:33:14]: The application application installation has started.

WRONG INFORMATION
The following errors were detected when the operation was performed.
* [2018-01-14 19:33:14] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
- The deployment and application program security zones do not match.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack tracking:
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest (AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri & appSourceUri, String & appManifestPath)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication (SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory & downloadTemp)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication (SubscriptionState & SubState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation (Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String & errorPageUrl, Uri & deploymentUri)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry (Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String & errorPageUrl)
--- End the stacking track from the previous location where an exception is triggered ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry (Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String & errorPageUrl)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker (Object Status)

INFORMATION ON TRANSACTIONS IN THE COMPANY ARRIVAL
There are no transaction details.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome (not IE) , then you need to have the "click-once" plug-in installed. If the problem still exists, then you need to clear the cache  `rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache`